# Serverfirepanel Zofe/rapyd show foreign object name

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Serverfire panel which uses Zofe/rapyd I like to show an other column such as the foreign key. I tested this:

```
$this->grid->add('kunde.name',"Kunden Id");
```

But this only shows up **{{kunde->name}}** at the Page.
My model looks like this:

```
class Regal extends Model {

protected $table = 'regale';

public function kunde()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Kunde');        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax in blade is {{$kunde->name}}  and I suggest to add a silent operator {{@$kunde->name}} to cover the "null" value case.